# gdbserver - glob could not process pattern '(null)'

Tags: windows, ncurses, clion, mingw-w64, gdbserver

```
gdbserver localhost:2159 test_app.exe
```

Whenever I type this kind of command
I got this kind of message:

> glob could not process pattern '(null)'.

Also, it doesn't matter which kind of terminal/[CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) I use on my Windows machine -
the result is always the same.

---

I would like to debug my PDCurses/NCurses app via CLion.
Every time when it encounters the `initscr()` function CLion says to me that:

> Redirection is not supported.

So the only workaround seems to be the usage of GDB Remote Debug.
But due to the problem described above [I am not sure if my settings are correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1grTw.png).

---

```
$ gdbserver --version
GNU gdbserver (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
gdbserver is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.
This gdbserver was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

Comment: Arriving soon:
https://patches-gcc.linaro.org/patch/4389/